# Error Parsing a string to a List

Tags: java, java-me, nokia

I have managed to fetch a string from the database and be able to store some of its elements in variable so as to reduce the number of times the app interacts with the databse. However I wanted the first element to be fetched from the database to be stored in a list but it keeps generating an error when i parse the string to a new list. please help

```
//String fetched from the database
final String[] rec = split(myresult,seperator);

//loc is the first String to be parsed to a String..
//desc is the 2nd string to be parsed to a textarea
//coords 3rd string which contains coordinates..
String  loc=rec[0];
final  String desc=rec[1];
String coords=rec[2];

//ERROR IS GENERATED HERE!!!
listmboya=new List(loc);
//Separate the coordinates in the string...
String seperator2=",";

String [] coordinates=split(coords,seperator2);

String lat=coordinates[0];
String lot=coordinates[1];

//convert them to floats..
item1=Float.parseFloat(lat);
item2=Float.parseFloat(lot);
```

Answer (score 2):

list is an iterface, 
try

```
   listmboya=new ArrayList();
   listmboya.add(loc);
```

Comment: `loc` is a `String`. I don't think there's an `ArrayList` constructor that receives a `String` as parameter.

Comment: @user1708393 from the code block posted, there's no guarantee that this will be the best solution for your problem, it would only let you compile until the `item2=...` line.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate `List` object. Its an `interface` and not a `class`. You need an `ArrayList` which is the implementing class of `List` and also, there is no constructor for `ArrayList` that takes String as parameter.

So, you need to create an `ArrayList<String>` and then add your String to it.

So you need to do it like this: -

```
List<String> listmboya=new ArrayList<String>();
listmboya.add(loc);
```

Make sure to declare your `listmboya` as `List<String>`

**UPDATE**: - Post some more Code in case this doesn't work. We need to look at more of them.

Comment: The error has gone. How do you add actionListener to the ArrayList created?

Comment: When a particular item on the now ArrayList is selected, there is an event or an action to be Performed (actionPerformed)

Comment: @user1708393 You can click the arrow besides an answer to mark it as accepted. And add a new question for your query. :)

Comment: I'm not seeing the arrow. This is my first time posting a question here.. Sorry for the nagging :)

Comment: @user1708393 Did you find the arrow? It is just below the voting area on the left side of every answer..

Answer (score 0):

**List** is the abstract class, can not be instantiated.
just try like this:

```
listmboya = new ArrayList<String>();
listmboya.add(loc);
```